# Android Videoview not play and Show black screen(Not go onprepare and onerror listener)

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I am trying to play m3eu video.All video are play but have problem one video.is not showing any error just show black screen.I am checking that it not go to onpreper listener and onError listener.Give my any solution. Thanks